# Filter First column of table Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I'm trying to build a select filter using Jquery for a HTML table, and I want to filter only the first column of that table, so far I've got this function:

```
$('#select').change(function() {
    var rows = $("#tablebody_hosts").find("tr").hide();
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        rows.filter(":contains(" + v + ")").show();
    })
});
```

How can I make this just search for the data in the first column of the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
rows.filter(function () {
    return $(this).children(':eq(0)').text().indexOf(v) !== -1;
}).show();
```

Instead of :

```
rows.filter(":contains(" + v + ")").show();
```

Doc : http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just wanted to know how I can match exactly the value of v for example if v is 3 then 13 or 23 will be included. Anyway to match exactly 3?

Comment: @PedroOliveira I've been mislead by the `:contains()` selector apparently.  Does this solution matches your requirements (strict equality) : `$.trim($(this).children(':eq(0)').text()) === v`?

Comment: @PedroOliveira De nada.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
  rows.filter(function(){
    return (data.indexOf($.trim($(this).children('td').first().text())) != -1);
 }).show();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate through the rows, Just try this,

```
rows.filter(function(){
    return (data.indexOf($.trim($(this).children('td').first().text())) != -1);
}).show();
```

Or

```
rows.filter(function(){
    return $.inArray($.trim($(this).children('td').first().text()),data);
}).show();
```

Comment: Sure. You're showing the cell instead of the row, moreover, `indexOf` return -1 if the given element is not present.

Comment: @wared Thanks for pointing out the mistakes, Am I still missing anything.?